# how to use python colorama?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, module, colorama

i trying to do colorful cmd, but its didnt working. windows 10 and i dont have any error. im doing it in the visual studio 2022

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

print('\033[31m' + 'some red text')
print('\033[39m')  # and reset to default color
print()
print(f"{Fore.RED}C{Fore.GREEN}O{Fore.YELLOW}L{Fore.BLUE}O{Fore.MAGENTA}R{Fore.CYAN}S{Fore.WHITE}!")
print(f"{Fore.RED}Red Text")
print(f"{Fore.GREEN}Green Text")
print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}Yellow Text")
print(f"{Fore.BLUE}Blue Text")
print(f"{Fore.MAGENTA}Magenta Text")
print(f"{Fore.CYAN}Cyan Text")
print(f"{Fore.WHITE}White Text")
print()
print(f"{Back.RED}B{Back.GREEN}A{Back.YELLOW}C{Back.BLUE}K{Back.MAGENTA}G{Back.CYAN}R{Back.WHITE}O{Back.RED}U{Back.GREEN}N{Back.YELLOW}D{Back.BLUE}!")
print(f"{Back.RED}Red Background")
print(f"{Back.GREEN}Green Background")
print(f"{Back.YELLOW}Yellow Background")
print(f"{Back.BLUE}Blue Background")
print(f"{Back.MAGENTA}Magenta Background")
print(f"{Back.CYAN}Cyan Background")
print(f"{Back.WHITE}White Background")
print()
print(f"{Style.DIM}S{Style.NORMAL}T{Style.BRIGHT}Y{Style.DIM}L{Style.NORMAL}E{Style.BRIGHT}!")
print(f"{Style.DIM}Dim Text")
print(f"{Style.NORMAL}Normal Text")
print(f"{Style.BRIGHT}Bright Text")
print()
print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}{Back.RED}C{Back.GREEN}{Fore.RED}O{Back.YELLOW}{Fore.BLUE}M{Back.BLUE}{Fore.BLACK}B{Back.MAGENTA}{Fore.CYAN}I{Back.CYAN}{Fore.GREEN}N{Back.WHITE}A{Back.RED}T{Back.GREEN}I{Back.YELLOW}O{Back.BLUE}N")
print(f"{Fore.GREEN}{Back.YELLOW}{Style.BRIGHT}Green Text - Yellow Background - Bright")
print(f"{Fore.CYAN}{Back.WHITE}{Style.DIM}Cyan Text - White Background - Dim")
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to fix. The code works as intended:

[image]

Whatever terminal you are using it apparently doesn't support this.

Comment: yes it work in cmd but if i open it in visual studio its didnt work why?

Comment: https://www.hizliresim.com/jdb0br4